# How to convert a .rik to .tif?

Tags: qgis, export

I have a quite large high-resolution map in a format called .rik from the Swedish land survey agency. 
I want that whole high resolution file in different format that can be used to print a map from a large area.

When i choose "Save as picture" in the Archive menu now, it only exports the view seen on the screen. 
If I zoom-out to see the full extent of the map and then export it the resolution is poor.

I want to export the whole file in the highest possible resolution.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which program/version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Go Raster->Convert->Translate

The dialog box has various options for the output.  Your are exporting to tiff so there should be no problem, but if you select a different output format, you'll need to edit the commandline options at the bottom by hand (the -of parameter).